# Servlet setStatus getting ignored and instead response code 200 being sent

Tags: java

I have a servlet which fetches regular data from the database and then sends the output to the customer end point. It is supposed to return different response codes and content based on the condition being encountered
eg: 222 is a correct execution while 444 shows an exception getting caught

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    LOG.debug("Hit");

    BufferedReader brin = new BufferedReader(request.getReader());

    BufferedWriter brout = new BufferedWriter(response.getWriter());

    JSONObject inputJSON;

    String temp;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

    int restid = 0;

    Connection conn = null;

    PreparedStatement st = null;

    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {

        if(request.getHeader("Authorization") == null) {
            response.setStatus(401);
            LOG.debug("Unauthorized entry detected");
            return;
        }

        while((temp=brin.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(temp);
        }

        inputJSON = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

        restid=inputJSON.getInt("restid");

        if(!ValidationTester.isValidRestIdInt(restid)) {
            response.setStatus(444);
            LOG.error("Invalid input received");
            return;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.setStatus(444);
        LOG.error("Error reading input "+e.toString());
        return;
    }finally {
        try {
            brin.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            //Do nothing
        }
    }

    try {

        String idtoken = request.getHeader("Authorization").split(" ")[1];

        if(restaurantRepoApp == null) {

            restaurantRepoApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance();

        }

        FirebaseToken firebaseToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(restaurantRepoApp).verifyIdTokenAsync(idtoken).get(10000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        if(firebaseToken == null || firebaseToken.getUid() == null) {

            response.setStatus(444);
            LOG.error("Error occurred while verifying the Id token from auth header, no uid found, token found null? "+(firebaseToken==null));
            return;

        }else {

            LOG.debug("ID token received in header "+idtoken+" found uid from the verified token "+firebaseToken.getUid());

        }

    }catch(Exception e) {

        if(e.toString().contains("expired")) {

            response.setStatus(111);
            LOG.debug("Token expired, ask the client to refresh it");
            return;

        }

        response.setStatus(444);
        LOG.error("Error occurred while verifying the Id token from auth header "+e.toString());
        return;
    }

    try {

        long currentTimeMillis = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")).getTimeInMillis();

        conn = HikariConnectionGetter.getConnection();
        //This will have a validation timeout of max 5s and connection timeout of 10s
        //Thus if this fails, let the thing fail so as to avoid timeout issues at client side

        st = conn.prepareStatement("select * from foodiniq_provalidity where restid=?");

        st.setInt(1,restid);

        rs = st.executeQuery();

        if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
            response.setStatus(333);
            LOG.debug("The restaurant has no bought pro validity pack or it has been deleted after expiry");
            return;
        }

        long expiryTimeFound = 0L;

        while(rs.next()) {

            if(rs.getLong("expirytime")<=currentTimeMillis) {
                response.setStatus(333);
                LOG.debug("The restaurant has no bought pro validity pack or it has been deleted after expiry");
                return;
            }

            expiryTimeFound = rs.getLong("expirytime");

        }

        response.setStatus(222);

        JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject();

        responseObject.put("expirytime",expiryTimeFound);

        brout.write(responseObject.toString());

        brout.flush();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        response.setStatus(444);
        LOG.error("Error occurred while entering bookmark "+e.toString());
    }finally{

        try{
            rs.close();
        }catch(Exception ee){
            //Do nothing
        }

        try{
            st.close();
        }catch(Exception ee){
            //Do nothing
        }

        try{
            conn.close();
        }catch(Exception ee){
            //Do nothing
        }

        try{
            brout.close();
        }catch(Exception ee){
            //Do nothing
        }

    }

}
```

This code was working fine till today and now for some reason, tomcat seems to be returning a response code of 200 and the expiry time data being sent is not received despite correct operation. However, the proper response and content is received on my local machine. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Great now absolutely no response codes work and no content gets delivered....